# How to enable bottom menu button in android 4.0 ICS

Tags: android, button, menu

I want to enable bottom menu button and Which theme will be use for this menu button.I try many theme but did not work for me by the any theme.How can I achieve this?. Thanks in Advance.[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

set `android:targetSdkVersion="8"`  in manifest.xml ,
Image is taken from Samsung galaxy nexus

**Example**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:maxSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: tanks for quick response  used this things but no response in bottom of the device

Comment: You can only decare into the maniufest <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"/>

Answer (score 0):

If your target-sdk is <4.0, you are not using support library in your project, and if you haven't used `ActionBarSherlock` then this overflow menu should appear automatically, if you've overriden `onOptionCreateMenu()` method, on phones that only have soft buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your targetSdkVersion in the manifest to 10 or less Android assumes your app depends on a menu button and will show it. Otherwise, menu items are available in the action bar.

Comment: to save room the action bar is hidden, thats why I  needed <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/> trick

Comment: Setting targetSdkVersion to 10 makes Eclipse complain: `Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply.` But what about if your app does not use any action bars? My app uses menus.