# Menu button wont show on Galaxy Tab 2

Tags: android

I am trying to show 3 dot menu on Galaxy Tab 2 (JB) and it just won't show. I changed target SDK to 13 and it still doesn't show on Galaxy Tab 2:
[image]

```
# Project target.
target=android-10
```

---

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

Does anyone have Galaxy Tab 2 to test it out? Did anyone get it working?

Comment: I think `android:targetSdkVersion="10"` but it is not recommended to use menu anymore. Actionbar should be used instead of.

Comment: The objective is to get rid of the legacy menu affordance, not to introduce it: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: can i use android:targetSdkVersion="11"? multitouch is not working in 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

set `android:targetSdkVersion="8"`  in manifest.xml ,
Image is taken from Samsung galaxy nexus

**Example**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:maxSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="8" />
```

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16271373/1218762)

Comment: @user1798049 do you have doubt ?

Comment: No don't use this else it will not show menus , multitouch is not working ? what does it means  ?