# I hide the ActionBar but I can't see the menu button in my `Nexus 4`

Tags: android

I hide the ActionBar but I can't see the menu button in my `Nexus 4`

I hide like this:

```
final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
bar.setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
bar.hide();
```

I can't see this:

[image]

Comment: you should have that button anyway

Comment: Here's how to enable it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16271413/379245 You must set a target SDK version to 10 or smaller. Otherwise, it is assumed that the menu is in the action bar.

Comment: Please don't target old SDK versions. The answer by @CommonsWare is correct.

Answer (score 2):

> cant see this

You are not supposed to see that. That is the sign of an app that either:

- has not been updated in years, or
- is written by somebody who wants the users to think that the app has not been updated in years

If you do not want an action bar, that's fine, but then implement your own menu within your own UI (e.g., using `PopupMenu`).

A discussion of the action bar, the overflow, and so on can be found in [this Android Developers Blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html).